# Hide Each Row That Doesn't Match The Current Week Plus The Next Twelve Rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Assuming today's date of Jan 26th, I have a Google Sheet I'm testing where column A rows 3, 15 and 27 have a dates entered (Jan 19th, Jan 26th and Feb 2nd).  I'm trying to hide the Jan 19th and Feb 2nd rows (along with their next 12 rows respectively).

I found an older post/solution that works to hide the date row for only row 3 (Jan. 19th).  I'm not certain how to adapt it to what I need.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
function hideRows() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var v = s.getRange("A:A").getValues();
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
for (var i = s.getLastRow(); i > 2; i--) {
    var t = v[i - 1];
    if (t != "") {
        var u = new Date(t);
        if (u < today) {
            s.hideRows(i);
        }
    }
}
```

| Previous Weeks Date (Hide Me) |
| --- |
| Hide Me 1 |
| Hide Me 2 |
| Hide Me 3 |
| Hide Me 4 |
| Hide Me 5 |
| Hide Me 6 |
| Hide Me 7 |
| Hide Me 8 |
| Hide Me 9 |
| Hide Me 10 |
| Hide Me 11 |
| Hide Me 12 |
| Current Week Date (Show Me) |
| Show Me 1 |
| Show Me 2 |
| Show Me 3 |
| Show Me 4 |
| Show Me 5 |
| Show Me 6 |
| Show Me 7 |
| Show Me 8 |
| Show Me 9 |
| Show Me 10 |
| Show Me 11 |
| Show Me 12 |
| Next Weeks Date (Hide Me) |
| Hide Me 1 |
| Hide Me 2 |
| Hide Me 3 |
| Hide Me 4 |
| Hide Me 5 |
| Hide Me 6 |
| Hide Me 7 |
| Hide Me 8 |
| Hide Me 9 |
| Hide Me 10 |
| Hide Me 11 |
| Hide Me 12 |

Jerome

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `Assuming today's date of Jan 26th, I have a Google Sheet I'm testing where column A rows 3, 15 and 27 have a dates entered (Jan 19th, Jan 26th and Feb 2nd). I'm trying to hide the Jan 19th and Feb 2nd rows (along with their next 12 rows respectively).`. Can you provide the sample input and output situations as the image? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: I would suggest to create a row in sheets like =if(isblank(a1),,weekday(a1)), have a cell with todays weekname like =weekday(today()) and then compare this. If all you want is filtering then the function filter() in sheets will take you there much faster than scripting...

Comment: Do you want to hide the dates = and greater than today right? And also the 12 following rows? Do the other rows have any information?

Comment: My apologies for not being clear enough.  I've added Column A of the sheet to further display what I'm after.

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure.

Comment: I changed it to a table.

Comment: The solution below is your definitive solution or an update? If it is an update, please post it on the question so other users are not confused by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution I am using.

```
function hideRows() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName("Dude");       // Enter sheet name

var row = s.getRange('A2:A').getValues();  // Enter column letter that has the text "hide" and  "unhide"
var cell = s.getRange('A1').getValue();

s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
for(var i=0; i < row.length; i++){ if(row[i] != cell) { s.hideRows(i+2, 1); }   // Value to hide
     
}
}
```